# How to add parameters to OnActionExecuting?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio

I want to add Params in current request in  OnActionExecuting() filter i tried this

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Params.Add("mid", "amogh");
```

It gives error that says this is `read only`.

I also want to access this added Params in next request.can i access this Params by using filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer object.

Comment: Why are you trying to add parameters? It seems a bit odd to do this... Or I'm missing something :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use the `ActionParameters` property (see **[ActionExecutingContext.ActionParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionexecutingcontext.actionparameters%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)**) - this allows you to see or change the parameters that will be passed to the action method.

Comment: can i access this ActionParameters by using filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer. in short i also want to access previous request parameters also i know i can get previoues request URI by using filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer in OnActionExecuting()

Comment: @user1629242 sounds like you want to add a value provider

Comment: @AndrasZoltan what i am doing is. i am developing an library which will prepare menus which is accessible for current AccessGroup for that i am passing menuid and moduleid as query string and i have an OnActionExecuting() filter to carry these Qstring in that i check if current request URL has both id or not if not i take it from UrlReferrer and set to current URL this works perfect if current request is GET if POST how can i pass this value and persist it to access for further Request.keep in mind that i m developing Class Lib so i cant do change in each Action.